# How do I change the currency symbol to a user-defined symbol in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, localization

I want to change the currency symbol of Turkey from "TL" to "₤".

I am using Windows 7. If I access the Control Panel and go to *Region and Language* > *Formats* > *Additional Settings* > *Currency*, the currency symbol is TL and the only options I have in the drop-down list are £, $ and €.

Is there a way to add ₤ to this drop-down list?

Answer (score 1):

Forget the list, there's no need for it.

Simply type your letter there like you type in Notepad. You can type anything you want and it will become your currency symbol.

Comment: Hi arioch,Thanks a lot for the help.
It worked for me.

Comment: Good. Then mark it as SO rules suggest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work